# Union all таблиц с разной структурой данных HIVE

Tags: sql, hive

Есть две таблицы: 
Таб 1.

```
tab1: Seg, Pase, Clave1, Clave2
```

Пример

```
Se1, pas1, ABC, DEF
```

Таб 2.

```
tab2: Clave1, Clave2
```

Пример

```
JKL, MNO
```

Мне нужно соеденить две таблицы, поставиь одну под другую. Логичнее всего исползовать union all. И в принципе работает. Но в таком случае в итоговой таблице часть строк колонок SEG и PAS помечаются как null.

А нужен такой результат:

```
 Se1, pas1, ABC, DEF
 Se1, pas1, JKL, MNO
```

Посоветуете что нибудь?

Версия сервера `HIVE 2.2.0`

Comment: А по какой причине отсутствующие во второй таблице поля в итоге получили значения именно из этой записи первой таблицы? Если из-за равенства двух имеющихся полей (кстати, а в первой таблице эта пара полей уникальна?) - так в подзапросе связать две таблицы, и UNION его с другой копией первой..

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39533/fill-null-with-previous-row-values-in-hive.html